# Refresh page after WordPress form submission, without 'Confirm Resubmission' alert

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have my form doing what it needs to (add/remove tag from post depending on whether it's there or not). But - once I submit the form the page doesn't update as intended, the $buttonTitle doesn't update unless I re-load the page in another tab. If I try to refresh I get the message 'Confirm Form Resubmission', I'm a complete noob to php forms, but here's my code...

```
<?php

$idTag = $current_user->ID;
$spitOutTag = (string)$idTag;

if (has_tag( $spitOutTag, $post )) {
    $buttonTitle = 'REMOVE TAG';
} else {
    $buttonTitle = 'ADD TAG';
} ?>

<form name="primaryTagForm" action="<?php echo the_permalink() ?>" id="primaryTagForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="newtags" id="newtags" value="<?php echo $current_user->ID; ?>" />
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'post_nonce', 'post_nonce_field' ); ?>
        <button id="btn-join" class="btn btn-lg" type="submit"><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></button>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() && isset( $_POST['newtags'] ) ) {

    if (has_tag( $spitOutTag, $post )) { 

        // Get all the tags as an array of names
        $tags = wp_get_post_tags( get_the_ID(), array('fields' => 'names') );

        // Remove the tag from the array
        $index = array_search( $idTag, $tags );
        unset( $tags[$index] );

        // Reset the tags
        wp_set_post_tags( get_the_ID(), $tags );

    } else {

        wp_set_post_tags(get_the_ID(), sanitize_text_field($_POST['newtags']), true );

    }   

} ?>
```

Comment: You'll need to render a new page. You cannot remove that warning because the page was generated from sent variables, so in order to refresh it, the browser needs to resend those vars to render the page again

Comment: ok thanks, do you know where I can get more info on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're assigning the tags after checking them, that's why the button doesn't change, you'll need to arrange your code like this:

First, checking if some tags were sent and apply it to the post:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() && isset( $_POST['newtags'] ) ) {
  ............
} ?>
```

Then checking the Button:

```
if (has_tag( $spitOutTag, $post )) {
    $buttonTitle = 'REMOVE TAG';
} else {
    $buttonTitle = 'ADD TAG';
} ?>
```

Finally printing the HTML:

```
<form name="primaryTagForm" action="<?php echo the_permalink() ?>"
   ....
</form>
```

Comment: ah great, this has fixed the updating problem yes. I still have the 'Confirm Form Resubmission' message but I'm guessing this is a separate issue.

Comment: Yes, that will ALWAYS happens if you refresh manually. That's how the web works. If it worked, select this as the answer ;)